# Why do I still recieve notifications from filtered applications

Tags: networking, filter, firewall, telegram

I don't know what site I should use for this question. I guess stackoverflow is the most relevant as I can't find any specific site for networking.

In my country the Telegram messenger application is currently filtered and can't be accessed without VPN etc. But I keep receiving some notifications every now and then from the web-application yet if I click on them the site will be opened and I won't be able to view the message because of the filtering and the web-app keeps showing that it's trying to connect but it can't connect. So what is happening here? If Telegram is blocked and I can't connect to it how can I receive notifications from it and if I'm getting notifications and thus there is a successful connection from my machine to telegram, how come I can't use the application?

Answer (score 2):

Telegram use different path for notification service. so the path may not be filtered yet

Comment: Why would it use a different path for that?

Comment: server load balancing.